# Sign in with Apple guide - the metadata endpoint is already in use by an identity provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sign-in-with-apple

Following the guide [Setting up Sign in with Apple as a Custom OpenID Connect identity provider](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) I get to the end, I click Save and I get the error:

> "The issuer 'https://appleid.apple.com' found at the metadata endpoint
>   {my endpoint} is already in use by an identity provider."

What am I missing? Is the guide still valid?

This question have also been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/20) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is shown when you have two custom identity providers, the metadata point for which have the same issuer.

Please check metadata document at `well known endpoints` (/.well-known/openid-configuration) for your existing custom identity providers.

Check for `issuer` field there. If you already have an issuer field on other metadata endpoints, you will get this error.

Azure AD B2C enforces the distinct issuer. The reason being that unique id of the user depends on the client Id in that system. If you have two apps in Facebook, Facebook will give you separate unique user Id for same user using different apps. So AADB2C wants that connection to one issuer is established through only one identity provider.

**Update1**
This seems to be a real issue. However the reasoning will be same. Will notify the engineering.

**Update2**
The fix is rolled out for this issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't have another custom identity provider defined. How can I change the issuer name (if that is the solution?). As I understand from the guide, that it has to be: "https://appleid.apple.com".