# Sign in with Apple under Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sign-in-with-apple

I would like to know if any of you have implemented "Sign in with Apple" under Azure AD B2C Environment.

I did not find clear information about how to implemented (Micrososft and Apple are not talking each other). I found trusted source at GitHub (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple), I followed the instruction, but did not work. Looks like there is some pieces of code missing or Apple/Microsoft/OpenId configuration has changed and this info is not included in the Post. I do not know.

My App was rejected by **Apple** because I am using additional identity providers (Social Networks) to sign in to my App, so Apple request to make their Identity Provider as an option ("Sign in with Apple").

> **Guideline 4.8 - Design - Sign in with Apple**
>
> We noticed that your app uses a third-party login service but does not offer Sign in with Apple.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent login option.
>
> **Resources**
>
> To learn more, see the Sign in with Apple [Overview](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/).

So Far, I follow the instruction/recommendation but i can not make it works.

Today Azure AD only let OpenID as the only identity provider option for Apple.

Problem 1.

If I followed the GitHub Post (above), I got the following error:

> Identity Provider Save Error
>   Cannot save  Identity Provider: The issuer 'https://appleid.apple.com' found at the metadata endpoint.

So, I changed the **issuer** for my App Service Id, then Azure let me Save the provider, but it is not working as expected. (problem reported here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/20)

Problem 2.

With the "new Issuer": My App ask for the AppleId (it looks working step 1), but nothing happens then (it did not create a user in the Azure AD, because nothing came to Azure) the App login remain in the AppleId.apple.com page forever (blank/white page)

**Please, I will like to know if any of you has similar situation, and how you solved it.**

Many thanks in advance

EDIT: 
I found some important information about OpenID and Apple

1. Open Letter from the OpenID Foundation to Apple Regarding Sign In with Apple [link](https://openid.net/2019/06/27/open-letter-from-the-openid-foundation-to-apple-regarding-sign-in-with-apple/)
2. Apple Successfully Implements OpenID Connect with Sign In with Apple, [link](https://openid.net/2019/09/30/apple-successfully-implements-openid-connect-with-sign-in-with-apple/)
3. 'Sign in with Apple' better but not perfect, says OpenID Foundation head, [link](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/10/02/sign-in-with-apple-better-but-not-perfect-says-openid-foundation-head)

Don't understand how Apple can force us to have "sign in with Apple" as an option if it not ready yet!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign in with Apple guide - the metadata endpoint is already in use by an identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971848/sign-in-with-apple-guide-the-metadata-endpoint-is-already-in-use-by-an-identit)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971848/sign-in-with-apple-guide-the-metadata-endpoint-is-already-in-use-by-an-identit

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, This is almost the same problem, but there is no clear solution. I do not know if it is Microsoft, Apple and/or OpenID problem. If somebody already have the solution, please share it with us. THANKS!

Comment: BlueOceans1st, this is a known issue, have been reported to the engineering team, we'll have a fix out soon.

Comment: Thanks very much @AbhishekAgrawal for this update. I cannot submit my App until this connection works.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal Any update for this issue?

Comment: I updated on original thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971848/sign-in-with-apple-guide-the-metadata-endpoint-is-already-in-use-by-an-identit that issue is resolved now

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal Please add your comment to the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal So does this means having Microsoflt Azure Login(as only option to login) in iPhone app now at this moment requires an option also for login with Apple ID, to successfully pass the review ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated on original thread as well. The issue is fixed now.

[Sign in with Apple guide - the metadata endpoint is already in use by an identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971848/sign-in-with-apple-guide-the-metadata-endpoint-is-already-in-use-by-an-identit)